# evrencoskun/tableview Cell click get full row value

Tags: java, android, tableview

On cell click, I am getting cell value but I need full row value, Is it possible? If there have any solution please help me. I am new in android development.

Comment: Hey there! To help you we need more information about what you're doing. If you read the question guidelines you'll find suggestions about how to ask questions which people will be able to answer, such as posting code that you've tried that hasn't worked. In your current question we can't see what you've tried to do, so we don't know what changes will get you the result that you're looking for :)

Comment: Any cell click I need the full row of all cell values of that selected cell. For example, if I click cell [0][0] as 2d array in table view cell then I need full 0 no row all cell value as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all cell items of the row using the `[getCellRowItems(int rowPosition)][1]` function. You just need a row position. Thankfully, TableView [ClickListener](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/wiki/1.6.-Creating-a-ClickListener) provides that info.

```
         /**
          * Called when user clicks any cell item.
          *
          * @param cellView  : Clicked Cell ViewHolder.
          * @param columnPosition : X (Column) position of Clicked Cell item.
          * @param rowPosition : Y (Row) position of Clicked Cell item.
          */
         @Override
         public void onCellClicked(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder cellView, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
             // get all the cell items of the row.
             List<YourCellModelObject> list = yourTableViewObject.getAdapter().getCellRowItems(rowPosition);
         }
```

You can also check [this page](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/wiki/1.4.1-TableView-Adapter-Helper-functions) for the same kind of implementations.